# Weird error: ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: android, apache, google-chrome, webkit, typo3

I'm experiencing weird issue with chrome, safari on iOS, and default Android browser. Browser is getting ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH when loading the homepage of my Typo3 site.

I've googled already and find out that this error might be related to:

1. Network connection issues, like we have a firewall somewhere in the network which spoils TCP/IP packets.
2. It might be not closed mysql connection resource.
3. It might be generic server misconfiguration.

It is possible important to say that server runs on CentOS linux machine. Web server is Apache v.2.2.29. PHP version is 5.3.29.

Exact steps to reproduce:

1. Open chrome network console.
2. Open the homepage of the site.
3. See how browser will fail loading the page.
4. Issue is reproducible on both HTTP and HTTPS virtual hosts (even if I left only one of them).

Some considerations:

1. Doesn't seem to be client computer related issue - it is reproducible on different PCs and iPads in our office
2. Doesn't seem to be network issue because it also happens when application runs on localhost.
3. Doesn't seem to be mysql issue, the only `mysql_close` call is performed correctly.
4. Issue is reproducible if I just do `view-source:` request in the browser, i.e. it is related to the document rendering, not images, javascript or smth like that.
5. I'm able to login to Typo3 backend without any issues. It is just front-end which is failing.
6. Clearing Typo3 cache helps for short term, for issue to appear again - we need to run Chrome Canary in mobile simulation mode.
7. Nothing is added to Apache error_log when issue happens, but there is smth in Apache access log:

   ```
   172.31.13.171 - - [11/Mar/2015:20:54:59 +0000] "GET /store/login-widget HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "TYPO3/6.1.7"
   94.79.153.74 - - [11/Mar/2015:20:54:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 39914 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36"
   ```

   I think that might be it, important thing is that in `/store/` folder sits Magento system, which is supposed to return parts of header in response to `/store/login-widget` request. But request to `/store/login-widget` works ok, as far as I can see.

Would be great to have any ideas about what I can check, I'm really out of ideas.

Comment: I don't see any notes here about the error logs - have you checked them? Typically (from my experience) this was a permission issue, or caching issue, or a combination of both.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks for the hint - added more details to the post, including logs info

Answer (score 4):

Looks like [here is the issue](http://web.archive.org/web/20160324035011/https://worksonmymachine.org/blog/net-err-content-length-mismatch-wtf), at least suggested solution is working for me. So, setting

```
config.enableContentLengthHeader = 0
```

helps to stop browser crashes, but live system still runs smoothly with that setting turned on. No idea what is the difference.